# refresh the page after the sound is completed

Tags: codeigniter, audio, embed

I'm using a codeigniter for my website. I'd like to have a sound triggered when user clicks the menu. But the page refresh so fast after I click it so that the sound can't be heard. How can I make the page refresh after the sound is completed?

Here is the html:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="[link1]">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="[link2]">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="[link3]">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
<span id="dummy"></span>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navigation").click(function(){
        $("#dummy").html("<embed src='<?=base_url()?>sound/testing.mp3' hidden='true' autostart='true' loop='false' />");
    });
});
```

Comment: i don't see how the page refreshes there the menu items are not even links

Comment: @Josh I've edited it. Any solutions for that?

Comment: One thing web visitors hate is unwelcome audio, just saying...

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return false` inside your function to avoid refresh just after the click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".navigation").click(function(){
            $("#dummy").html("<embed src='<?=base_url()?>sound/testing.mp3' hidden='true' autostart='true' loop='false' />");
return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't do much work with audio, so Im not sure how the compatibility for this is but your solution should be somewhere along the lines of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navigation a").click(function(e){
        document.nextPage = $(this).attr('href')
        $("#dummy").html("<embed src='<?=base_url()?>sound/testing.mp3' hidden='true' autostart='true' loop='false' onended='followLink();' />");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function followLink(){
   document.location.href = document.nextPage;
}
```

where you are using the onended event to move on.

### update

this is a batter way of doing the same thing http://jsfiddle.net/joshK/d5eNu/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".navigation a").click(function(e){
        var nextPage = $(this).attr('href');
        var audioObj = $("<audio>").attr({
            "hidden":true,
            "src":"<?=base_url()?>sound/testing.mp3"
        }).bind("ended",function(){//when sound finished playing follow the link

           document.location.href = nextPage;

        }).appendTo("#dummy");

        audioObj[0].play();
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent the page from refreshing 
    });
});
```